Are Li-ion drone batteries chemically and electronically similar to cellphone Li-ion batteries?
I have an old Huawei E5372 Mobile Hotspot with a removable battery. I'm thinking of buying another battery so I could simply swap batteries before they run low. Basically, I'd be charging one battery while I use the other.
The problem with such a scheme is that the only charger available for the battery is the device itself. I've therefore searched for alternatives. The first thought that came to my mind is. Why aren't there any universal "flat" cell battery chargers similar to the one for common cylindrical batteries such as the AA NiMH and 18650 LiFePO4.
My informal web research brought me to the chargers used for radio-controlled aerial drones. Most of them apparently use some sort of lithium-ion battery with all sorts of weird connectors at the end. My understanding is that they're called in the industry as Li-ion balance chargers because they're able to handle multi-cell batteries, using a set of power and data connectors.
The interesting thing is that these Li-ion chargers can also charge single-cell batteries without the data (balance) connector.
Am I wrong to assume that these Li-ion drone batteries are chemically and electronically similar to cellphone batteries?

Another option could be to try and source another identical used mobile hotspot and just use it for charging.


Are Li-ion drone batteries chemically and electronically similar to cellphone Li-ion batteries?

They are all Li-ion batteries, but a drone uses multiple cells in series (higher voltage, requires balancing) and a cell phone uses a single cell (3.7 V, no need for balancing). Typically, both drone and cell phone batteries use pouch Li-ion cells, but that's just how they're packaged. Inside, they use the same technology. There are a few different Li-ion chemistries, so cell phones may use different Li-ion chemistries and drones may use different Li-ion chemistries, but it's most likely that a drone and a cell phone both use a LCO (Cobalt) Li-ion chemistry (3.7 V).
Yes, a charger for a drone battery that supports a single cell can be used to charge a single cell battery. A problem is, though, that, if the cell phone battery includes a protector BMS, then the BMS won't turn on its switch until after it has had a successful handshake with the phone. So, you won't be able to charge it with anything but the correct phone. Even if the battery lets you charge it, the second problem is that the drone charger will hit the phone battery with a whopping high current that will degrade the phone battery in just a few cycles. Li-ion cells must be charged nice and slow to achieve the specified lifetime. Ideally, over 2 hours. A drone charger will charge the phone battery in 5 or so minutes. That's really bad for the Li-ion cell inside the cell phone battery.

For the last point, the issue is indeed to have the charger use the "right" current for the battery, which is usually proportional to the battery capacity. Some chargers are configurable, others aren't, and those that are do not necessarily have the "right" setting for the intended battery (RC vehicles usually have larger batteries which use higher charging currents, so they don't necessarily scale down to the currents for smaller phone batteries).

Another important thing to watch out: polarity. For some reason RC vehicle batteries and other (otherwise identical) batteries used in IoT devices use the same connector but with reverse polarity. Phone batteries usually have different connectors but one would have to find the right polarity, in addition to finding a way to hook up the battery to the charger.

I've been watching a YouTube video (4N4tlSfITqA by UAVFutures) showing what looks like a thumb-sized single-cell drone battery. The charger the presenter uses appears to be fully configurable regarding the current and voltage. My other concern, besides the current, is the connectors. How do I wire the charger with its pin/plug based connectors to a cellphone LiPo battery's flat terminals?

"My other concern, besides the current, is the connectors. " That's a different question. Start a new thread.

Actually that was part of my question before, I believe, you edited the title?
